# MySQL composite key best practice

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, composite-key

I suppose this is a performance question.

Does the order matter when creating a composite key?

In my instance the composite key is being created using a 128 bit char called hash and a foreign (int) key called user_id.

For example would  (`hash`, `user_id`) be faster than (`user_id`, `hash`) ?

Would the composite key be slower for example if it was used in a join ?

```
CREATE INDEX composite_hash_user_id_index ON `user_false_positives` (`hash`, `user_id`);
```

Comment: Yes. It does. But is x faster than y? That's a harder question.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the feedback. When you say 'MySQL uses the left most index' are you talking about the left part of the composite key. Is that part of the index used first?

Comment: If your question is about *creating* the index, then the answer is essentially no.  If the question is about *using* the index, then the order matters.

Comment: I'll update the answer

Comment: Hi Gordon. I was talking about the use of the index after its creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order in composite key matters a lot. MySQL uses the left most index, so it depends on the query you want to run. you can make a covering index. Create an index on(a,b) then another index on b alone. There are a lot of caveats in regards to indexing. Read the slides below
http://www.percona.com/sites/default/files/presentations/PMU-Bueno-Aires-2013-MySQL-Indexing-Best-Practices.pdf

**Left most index example:** if you have index on (a,b) and run

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY a
```

it will use index but

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY b
```

does not. so having another index on b alone will ensure that the index is used when ordering the data.

Comment: Sam, If I try insert using this composite key will it be slower than having the UNIQUE composite setup the other way around (user_id, hash) ?

Comment: as far as writes it is the same if hash and user_id have the same uniqueness ration over the total data. Write restructures the index so it is tricky to say.

Answer (score 0):

The order is important; the order should match your where statement in your query otherwise the index won't be used 
if you used a where clause in your select statement like "where user_id=1 and hash='xxxxx'" and your index was hash,user_id then the index will NOT be used.
more examples are available here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html